# Maven war packaging of transitive modules

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependencies, packaging

I have a web-app which provides an implementation of an API that I have written. So, I have a set of three artifacts: my-webapp (war), my-api (jar) and my-impl (jar). The pom's are straight-forward where: my-impl lists my-api as a dependency, and my-webapp lists my-impl as a dependency. When I run mvn install, I expect my-impl to pull in my-api during packaging into WEB-INF/lib. But it is pulling in only my-impl.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it not expected to work this way?

**Update:** If this helps, I keep getting this warning:

> [WARN] The POM for mine:my-impl:jar:1.1.0.0 is invalid, transitive
>   dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for
>   more details

The POM's are as follows:

*Packager:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
    <version>${product.version}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Webapp Packager</name>
    <description>Webapp Packager</description>
    <modules>
        <module>my-webapp</module>
        <module>my-api</module>
        <module>my-impl</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

*Webapp:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mine</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
        <version>${product.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Webapp</name>
    <description>Webapp</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mine</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${product.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*API:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mine</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
        <version>${product.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>API</name>
    <description>API</description>
</project>
```

*Implementation:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mine</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
        <version>${product.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Impl</name>
    <description>Impl</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mine</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-api</artifactId>
            <version>${product.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Show the pom files please.

Comment: Based on the given warning i would assume you have either a wrong version in your pom's? I hope you don't try to use `${project.version}` in your parent entries ? What are you using release version instead of SNAPSHOT's? Best would be having the real pom file of the module which caused the warning.

Comment: @khmarbaise What is wrong with using a defined property called `project.version`? How else can I centralize the version of the product components?

Comment: That will not work in Maven the way you do it?. I'm just talking about using a placeholders `<version>${product.version}</version>` like this. How did you call your maven build ? Apart from that if this would be possible how can your build be reproducible in any way. If you use maven-release-plugin best choice or sometime using versions-maven-plugin to help with the version numbers in the parent etc.

Comment: Try setting a real version number (e.g. 0.1-SNAPSHOT) in your parent POM, and remove the `<version>` elements from the module POMs.  The child modules will inherit the version from the parent.  Then run Maven from the parent directory (`mvn clean install`).  Does that work?

Comment: @user944849 But how should my `<parent>` tag look like? Currently it also contains the version of the parent - that is required, and AFAIK that cannot be inherited.

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you post an example code snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now, your "packager" POM is both an aggregator (since it has modules) and a parent (since all of the modules refer to it in their `<parent>` elements).  Thus, the "packager" POM **must** have an explicit version, you may not use the ${project.version} placeholder.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Webapp Packager</name>
    <description>Webapp Packager</description>
    <modules>
        <module>my-webapp</module>
        <module>my-api</module>
        <module>my-impl</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

In the child modules, the `<parent>` element will look like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-webapp-packager</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Then, a `mvn clean install` should work.